# I have a confusion with a logic used for picking random number

Tags: javascript

I have this following javascript code

```
var rnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1;
```

now my doubt is why are they adding one is it to exclude 0 or to include 50 while finding the random number. Please provide me with the correct answer with an explanation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/math/random <-- read the description

Comment: "*is it to exclude 0 or to include 50*" - both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)

[This definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) means that if you multiply the `random()` by `50`, as you did, you will get a maximum of `49.9`. To enable getting the number `50` as well (while avoiding receiving the `0`), you will need to add `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what each step does in `Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1;`:

- `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 (not including 1)
- `* 50` multiplies that number by 50, so now we're in the range between 0 and 50 (50 not included)
- `Math.floor()` converts that number (float) into an integer by rounding down, the range is now between 0 and 49 (49 included)
- `+ 1` changes the range to between 1 and 50

You were right.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same thing on both ends. You will always add 1. Suppose the number is 0 (lowest possible output) then you + 1. You now have 1 and you will never get 0 because if it's 0 you're always going to add one and get 1. --> 1 is the lowest possible output. You will never get 1 with Math.random. 49 is the highest possible output. Every time you get the highest number, 49, you + 1 and get 50. --> 50 becomes the highest possible output.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()`'s range is essentially `0` to `0.99999999999999` repeating.

0 times 50 is 0. That rounded down is still 0. Then plus 1 is 1, making 1 the minimum result.

0.99999999999999 times 50 is 49.99999999999999. That rounded down is 49. Then plus 1 is 1, making 50 the maximum result.

That being said, if you want a simpler and more readable solution, I recommend [randojs](https://randojs.com). You can use it like this:

```js
console.log( rando(1, 50) );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```